# Chrome devtools frontend source panel FileSystem not work

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I compile and package the chrome-devtools-frontend sourcecode ,then i use frontend from path out/Default/gen/front_end。 On source panel， I click fileSystem but it not work。
Who can tell me is this a bug？
And how to fix this bug，i try but it‘s too difficult。
Looking forward to your reply.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6UIWq.png)

Comment: Sounds like a bug in Chrome.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.